# I can't connect to a server ( volley ) with android app. + server with database communication via PFP

Tags: java, php, database, server

I have a connection file and a register file (both are in php) the connection file works, but the register one, not. 
Here are my php files

```
<?php
$db_name="id1892492_bazadedate";
$mysql_username="id1892492_paultifrea";
$mysql_password="asd1231234";
$server_adress="localhost";
$conn=mysqli_connect($server_adress,$mysql_username,$mysql_password,$db_name);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
else{
echo "connection succes";
} 

?>
```

and the second one:

```
<?php 
require "conn.php";
$name = $_POST["name"];
$email = $_POST["email"];
$user_name = $_POST["user_name"];
$password = $_POST["password"];
$sql = "select * from user_info where email like '".$email." ';";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,sql);
$reponse = array();
if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0)
{
    $code = "reg_failed";
    $message = "User already exist…..";
    array_push($response,array("code"=>$code, "message"=>$message));
    echo json_encode ($response);
}
else
{
$sql = "insert into allaccounts values('".$name. "', '".$email. "', '".$user_name. "', '".$password. "');
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sqli);
$code= "reg_succes";
$message= "Thank you for register with us. Now you can login…..";
array_push($response,array("code"=>$code, "message"=>$message));
echo json_encode($response);
}
mysqli_close($conn);
```

For register I use name,,email,username,password. Why doesn't work?

Comment: does the missed double quote in that line `$sql = "insert into allacc....` is just a typo?

Comment: I don't understand the question. I have a table into the database called allaccounts. There is the place where I want to put the new account after registering

Comment: the whole line is missing a double quotes at the end of that line, is this just a typo ?

Comment: It is not a typo, What should I do to fix it? Sorry I have no ideea nothing about php and I have to finish this for school...

Comment: `$sql = "insert into allaccounts values('".$name. "', '".$email. "', '".$user_name. "', '".$password. "')";` note the double quote before the semi-colon